# dynamic where condition in SQL from a configurable table

Tags: sql, oracle

CONDITION TABLE (T_CONDITION_TABLE)

```
COLUMN_NAME    COLUMN_VALUE
USER COUNT      0 
USER COUNT      1
STATUS          ACTIVE
STATUS          APPROVED
```

Suggest a query:

```
SELECT * FROM T_MASTER_TABLE WHERE ---- IN (SELECT * FROM T_CONDITION_TABLE)
```

The records in T_CONDITION_TABLE is dynamic and can include new values frequently.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please format your code with the `{}` button in the editor, not fixed HTML. There's more help on the formatting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). More [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/152099) too.

Comment: @hims056 I need to fill in the blanks after WHERE in the above query

Comment: Your question still doesn't make much sense. Please provide sample data for CONDITION and MASTER tables, input and expected output for your query. Also provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want as output is all the records in the T_MASTER_TABLE where your records satisfy the Status in T_CONDITION_TABLE, then u can use the WHERE Condition as

```
WHERE STATUS IN(Select DISTINCT STATUS FROM T_CONDITION_TABLE)
```

If you want to limit it with the user count use this.

```
WHERE COUNT(USER) IN(SELECT DISTINCT USERCOUNT FROM T_CONDITION TABLE)
```

If you want still more clearer answers, phrase your question properly.